# Is there a VSCode extension/setting for SQL files that will highlight the column of the selected value?

Tags: sql, sqlplus, visual-studio-code

This feature on IntelliJ by default, but my employer requires me to use VSCode.

It's very tedious to look at an SQL file and have to count the columns to get to the see if you're looking at the correct value.

So if this is my insert statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
```

the **PostalCode** column would be highlighted when my cursor is placed on the **'4006'** value here:

```sql
VALUES ('Cardinal', 'Tom B. Erichsen', 'Skagen 21', 'Stavanger', '4006', 'Norway');
```

My Google-fu has failed me so far. I have tried several extensions too. Does anyone know if/how this can be done?

Comment: and this was already the top result when I searched... so I guess the answer is "not yet as of today". (as a side-note: it's not a feature in IntelliJ by default, only in the Ultimate edition)

Comment: Its in DataGrip as well and is super useful

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "Rainbow csv" extension and rename the *.sql filename to *.csv.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).